# WCF Service library Request.MapPath - where is it

Tags: wcf

I am trying to run ana exe file by the service on the server. But I cannot find Request.MapPath. What namespace do I need to import? The way I try to run the exe is like:

```
   System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("~/view");
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "-x 2";
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("myProg.exe");
        process1.Start();
```

Do you thinkthis is a right way to run the exe. Doyou have any alternatives? Where is Request class

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e7ykf56.aspx This shows the namespace. (System.Web)

Comment: Unless the service is being hosted by IIS and is running in ASP.Net compatability mode, HttpRequest will not be available to his service.